# How to downgrade from 19.10 beta to mainstream 19.10?

Tags: updates, beta, 19.10

I upgraded to Ubuntu 19.10 beta before the stable branch released using `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` now that the stable version of 19.10 has released, how do I downgrade to 19.10 stable without re-installing the entire os?

Comment: Just do nothing. The release you're on is now stable.

Comment: Are you sure? If they add new things to the dev branch won't it update to those?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure! No, you won't. Check your `/etc/apt/sources.list` to verify.

Comment: This question is specific to a release of Ubuntu which has reached its end of standard support or end of life date, and is not related to asking for help to upgrade to a supported release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jake stated, it automatically moved to the stable branch when 19.10 came out.